# Rigorous construction of fermionic field theory?

Tags: reference-request, mp.mathematical-physics, quantum-field-theory

In section X.7 of [Reed & Simon's book](https://www.amazon.com.br/II-Fourier-Analysis-Self-Adjointness-2/dp/0125850026) there is a nice rigorous construction of the free scalar field theory which applies to the Klein-Gordon field.

**Question:** Are there references which discuss, in analogous fashion, the construction of (rigorous) fermionic field theories? At the moment, I'm more interested in the Dirac field theory because it includes the spin and two kinds of creation and annihilation operators.

Comment: Just a remark: Fermionic QFTs are easier to construct than Bosonic ones.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is the construction of the C${}^*\!$-algebra of canonical anticommutation relations (CAR's), which is actually somewhat easier than the construction of free bosonic fields: given any complex pre-Hilbert space $\mathfrak{h}$, which may be thought of as our "one-particle" space, define the unital *-algebra $\text{CAR}_0(\mathfrak{h})$ given by the generators $a(f),a^*(f)=a(f)^*$, $f\in\mathfrak{h}$ (respectively, the *annihilation* and *creation* operators for the particle with wave function $f$), and the following relations:

- The map $f\mapsto a(f)$ is *anti-linear* (hence the map $f\mapsto a^*(f)$ is *linear*);
- $\{a(f),a(g)\}=0$, where $\{A,B\}=AB+BA$ is the *anti-commutator* of two elements $A,B$ in an associative algebra (hence $\{a^*(f),a^*(g)\}=\{a(f),a(g)\}^*=0$);
- $\{a(f),a^*(g)\}=\langle f,g\rangle\mathbf{1}$, where we assume that the scalar product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ of $\mathfrak{h}$ is anti-linear in the first variable and linear in the second variable.

Notice that the CAR's imply that $$(a^*(f)a(f))^2=a^*(f)\{a(f),a^*(f)\}a(f)=\|f\|^2a^*(f)a(f)\ ,\quad f\in\mathfrak{h}$$ hence if there is a C${}^*\!$-norm $\|\cdot\|$ on $\text{CAR}_0(\mathfrak{h})$, we must have $$\|(a^*(f)a(f))^2\|=\|a^*(f)a(f)\|^2=\|f\|^2\|a^*(f)a(f)\|\ ,$$ therefore $\|a(f)\|=\|a^*(f)\|=\|f\|$ for all $f\in\mathfrak{h}$. In other words, unlike for bosonic fields, fermionic creation and annihilation operators are necessarily *bounded*, thanks to the Pauli exclusion principle encoded in the CAR's. To show that such a C${}^*\!$-norm actually exists, notice that there is a nontrivial *-representation of $\text{CAR}_0(\mathfrak{h})$ in the fermionic (i.e. anti-symmetric) Fock space $\mathfrak{F}_-(\mathfrak{h})$ generated by $\mathfrak{h}$: $$\mathfrak{F}_-(\mathfrak{h})=\bigoplus^\infty_{n=0}\wedge^n\mathfrak{h}\ ,$$ where $\wedge^0\mathfrak{h}=\mathbb{C}$, $\wedge^1\mathfrak{h}=\mathfrak{h}$, and $\wedge^n\mathfrak{h}$ for $n>1$ is the vector space generated by the $n$-fold wedge (i.e. anti-symmetrized tensor) product of elements of $\mathfrak{h}$: $$f_1\wedge\cdots\wedge f_n=\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{\sigma\in\mathbb{S}_n}\epsilon_\sigma f_{\sigma(1)}\otimes\cdots\otimes f_{\sigma(n)}\ ,$$ where $\mathbb{S}_n$ is the group of permutations of $n$ elements and $\epsilon_\sigma$ ( = $(-1)^{inv(\sigma)}$, $inv(\sigma)=$number of inversions of $\sigma\in\mathbb{S}_n$) is the sign of the permutation $\sigma$, endowed with the scalar product $$\langle f_1\wedge\cdots\wedge f_n,g_1\wedge\cdots\wedge g_n\rangle=\det[\langle f_i,g_j\rangle]\ .$$ The direct sum is assumed to be orthogonal. The action of $a(f),a^*(f)$ on $\mathfrak{F}_-(\mathfrak{h})$ is given by $$a(f)\lambda=0\ ,\,a^*(f)\lambda=\lambda f\ ,\quad\lambda\in\mathbb{C}\ ,$$ $$a(f)f_1\wedge\cdots\wedge f_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\langle f,f_1\rangle f_2\wedge\cdots\wedge\cdots\wedge f_n\ ,$$ $$a^*(f)f_1\wedge\cdots\wedge f_n=\sqrt{n+1}f\wedge f_1\wedge\cdots\wedge f_n\ ,\quad f_1,\ldots,f_n\in\mathfrak{h}\ .$$ It is easy to verify that this defines a *-representation of $\text{CAR}_0(\mathfrak{h})$ by bounded linear operators on $\mathfrak{F}_-(\mathfrak{h})$ (boundedness is guaranteed by the CAR's as shown above). This ensures that the completion of $\text{CAR}_0(\mathfrak{h})$ w.r.t. the maximal C${}^*\!$-norm $\|\cdot\|$ is a C${}^*\!$-algebra $\mathfrak{A}$ acting on the Fock Hilbert space $\overline{\mathfrak{F}_-(\mathfrak{h})}$, called the *CAR algebra* associated to $\mathfrak{h}$. As written, one is only able to define *Majorana* (i.e. Hermitian) fermionic field operators $$\psi_R(f)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(a^*(f)+a(f))\ ,$$ from which $a(f)$ and $a^*(f)$ may be recovered through the formula $$a(f)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\psi_R(f)+i\psi_R(if))\ ,\,a^*(f)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\psi_R(f)-i\psi_R(if))\ ,\quad f\in\mathfrak{h}\ .$$ We remark that the map $f\mapsto\psi_R(f)$ is only *real* linear.

To obtain the actual Dirac fields, $\mathfrak{h}$ needs to have the form $\mathfrak{h}=\mathfrak{k}\oplus\bar{\mathfrak{k}}$, where this direct sum is *orthogonal* and $\bar{\mathfrak{k}}$ is equal to $\mathfrak{k}$ as a *real* vector space, but with the *complex* scalar multiplication equaling that of $\mathfrak{k}$ composed with complex conjugation of the scalar factor. In other words, we have that for all $f,g\in\mathfrak{k}$, $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$ (**edit - November 11th 2022**, see Alan Garbarz's comment below) $$(f,g)+(f',g')=(f+f',g+g')\ ,\,\alpha(f,g)=(\alpha f,\bar{\alpha}g)$$ and $$\langle (f,f'),(g,g')\rangle=\langle f,g\rangle+\overline{\langle f',g'\rangle}=\langle f,g\rangle+\langle g',f'\rangle\ .$$ The above definition for the scalar product of $\mathfrak{h}$ from that of $\mathfrak{k}$ guarantees sesquilinearity as well as the mutual orthogonality of both direct summands w.r.t. each other. These correspond respectively to the particle and antiparticle sectors. Defining $$b(f)=a((f,0))\ ,\,c(f)=a((0,f))\ ,\quad f\in\mathfrak{k}\ ,$$ one can define the *Dirac field operators* $$\psi(f)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(b(f)+c^*(f))\ ,\psi^*(f)=\psi(f)^*=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(c(f)+b^*(f))\ ,\quad f\in\mathfrak{k}\ .$$ Now, thanks to the definition of $\bar{\mathfrak{k}}$, we have that $f\mapsto c(f)$ is actually *linear*, therefore $f\mapsto\psi(f)$ is *antilinear* and $f\mapsto\psi^*(f)$ is *(complex) linear*, contrary to the case of Majorana field operators. The above yields the *CAR's in Dirac form* $$\{b(f),b(g)\}=\{b(f),c(g)\}=\{c(f),c(g)\}=\{b(f),c^*(g)\}=\{c(f),b^*(g)\}=0\ ,$$ $$\{b(f),b^*(g)\}=\{c^*(f),c(g)\}=\langle f,g\rangle\mathbf{1}$$ for all $f,g\in\mathfrak{k}$, hence $$\{\psi(f),\psi(g)\}=0\ ,\,\{\psi(f),\psi^*(g)\}=\langle f,g\rangle\mathbf{1}\ .$$ All that is left is the construction of the one-particle pre-Hilbert space $\mathfrak{k}$, which can be identified with the space of initial data for positive-energy solutions of the Dirac equation.

We point that a similar procedure to that used to obtain Dirac fields can be employed for the free *complex* (bosonic) scalar field, which also enjoys a similar concept of particle and antiparticle sectors.

Apart from the last section on Dirac fields, all of the above may be found e.g. in Section 5.2 of the book by Ola Bratteli and Derek W. Robinson, *Operator Algebras and Quantum Statistical Mechanics 2. Equilibrium States, Models in Quantum Statistical Mechanics* (2nd. ed., Springer-Verlag, 1997).

Comment: Pedro, thanks for the answer. Although I'm not much familiar with $C^{*}$-algebras, I got the idea and appreciate the details and quality of your exposure. I know Bratelli & Robinson's book, so I might need to learn a little bit of $C^{*}$-algebra to fully understand your reasoning. In any case, your answer will be an important guide for me. Also, this discussion led me to think about another topic, and I should post another question soon.

Comment: You can look at Volume 1 of Bratteli-Robinson for an introduction to C*-algebras. Another nice book on the subject is G. Murphy's *C${}^*\!$-Algebras and Operator Theory*, but BR1 is more than enough to follow Volume 2.

Comment: I will take a look at both references! Thanks!

Comment: Pedro, by the way, you probably know this but there is a book by E. de Faria and W. de Mello called "Mathematical Aspects of Quantum Field Theory" where the quantization of Dirac fields is briefly discussed. But, there, the authors introduce Grassmann variables instead and I don't understand where the quantization is actually discussed. Anyways, I thought the quantization using Grassmann variables was used only when one is trying to quantize it via path integrals. If possible, could you comment on that?

Comment: Yes, I do know the book and his authors. The families of fermionic creation and annihilation operators generate each a Grassmann algebra - this is implicit in the CAR's. The (non-zero) anti-commutation relation relating both families to each other is the one involving Planck's constant $\hbar$, which is tacitly set to one in the above discussion - that's the only place where the CAR algebra differs from a Grassmann algebra, the one which makes it " quantum". As $\hbar\rightarrow 0$, both kinds of algebras coalesce - that's why we need the latter when quantizing fermions with path integrals.

Comment: sorry to revive the discussion after all this time, but I've been studying your answer and I'd like to ask whether it is possible for you to be a little more explicit about that the space $\mathfrak{k}$ should be. You mean $\mathfrak{k} = \operatorname{ker}(H_{D}-E)$, where $H_{D}$ is the Dirac operator $H_{D} := i\gamma^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}-m$ on $L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{4};\mathbb{C}^{4})$?

Comment: Not quite. One way to define $\mathfrak{k}$ is e.g. to take the completion of $\mathscr{D}(\mathbb{R}^4;\mathbb{C}^4)$ w.r.t. the scalar product $$\langle f,g\rangle=\langle 1,\psi(f)\psi^*(g)1\rangle=\langle 1,b(f)b^*(g)1\rangle=\omega(\overline{f},g)\ ,$$ where $\omega$ is the Wightman 2-point distribution of the Dirac field. One way to define the latter is as the positive-frequency part of the causal commutator $S=S^R-S^A$, which is the difference between the retarded and advanced fundamental solutions $S^R,S^A$ of the Dirac operator.

Comment: $S^R$ and $S^A$, on their turn, can be obtained by respectively applying the "conjugate" Dirac operator $i\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu+m$ to respectively $\Delta^R\otimes\delta$ and $\Delta^A\otimes\delta$, where $\Delta^R$ and $\Delta^A$ are respectively the retarded and advanced fundamental solutions of the Klein-Gordon operator $\Box+m^2$ with the same mass and $\delta$ is the four-dimensional Kronecker delta.

Comment: Using the Fourier transform, one can rewrite $\omega(\overline{f},g)$ in terms of initial data for positive-energy solutions of the Dirac equation, as I mentioned in my answer above. The advantage of the form I've chosen in the two comments above is that it's explicitly Poincaré-covariant.

Comment: Pedro, thanks again for the comments. Well, I should apologize for my ignorance, but I've  never have contact with any of those things, so it is really hard to me to follow your reasoning. On the other hand, this is the crucial part of the problem, since it provides the bridge between the general picture and the Dirac field quantization, the example I'm interested in. I don't think I can get where I want without undertanding your latest comments. Maybe you could suggest some references to me? It would be of  huge help! And again,thanks for your patience.

Comment: Pedro, if you could include some brief discussion to guide me, that would be great! Your comments are always really helpful. In the meantime I'll take a look at the reference you mentioned! Thanks again!

Comment: The formulae for the Wightman 2-point function and the other Green functions for the Dirac field are discussed with proper care in the comprehensive book by N. N. Bogolyubov,  A. A. Logunov, A. I. Oksak and I. T. Todorov, "General Principles of Quantum Field Theory" (Kluwer, 1990), see Section 8.4, pp. 340-358 therein. I'll try to include a brief discussion on this into my answer in the next few days.

Comment: Pedro, let me take the oportunity to ask: what's your opinion on Arai's book "Analysis on Fock Spaces and Mathematical Theory of Quantum Field"? It has less algebraic approach and seems more suitable to me.

Comment: I don't know this book, I'll have a look at it.

Comment: Perhaps we should move this discussion to chat if we see fit to continue it in the future.

Comment: Pedro, okay. I don't know how to start a chat tho. This book does not seem well known. Yet, it seems pretty good to me. I'd like to know your opinion (you can take its discussion on the quantization of the Dirac field as a parameter for instance).

Comment: OK, I've had a quick look at Arai's book. The book is certainly more pedestrian in the sense that it delivers more background material and tries to be closer to traditional QFT textbooks for physicists. The more algebraic approach I follow in my answer is equivalent but more, say, efficient - it's quite shorter and easier to generalize to other space-times (you can do it for sections of any vector bundle). Particularly regarding the one-particle space $\mathfrak{k}$, I've deliberately kept Fourier analysis to a minimum since this technique is not available in curved space-times.

Comment: Pedro, very nice! Always good to hear from experts. So, Arai's book seems like a nice place to start while I'm learning the backgrounds for the algebraic approach right?

Comment: If you choose to follow this path, I'd suggest you to read Arai's book in tandem with some standard QFT textbook for physicists, so you can understand better the latter from a mathematical viewpoint and, at the same time, keep track of why certain things are defined the way they are in the former. I emphasize, however, that the algebraic approach is not only more efficient as I've just argued, it's also more robust when you move to interacting fields. The whole "canonical" framework as e.g. developed in Arai's book tends to break down in several places when interactions come to play.

Comment: Pedro, could it be that in the Dirac construction, as it is written, the anticommutator $\left\{\psi(f),\psi^*(g)\right\}=\text{Re}\langle f , g \rangle \textbf{1}$?
Instead, in order to get the inner product on th RHS of the anticommutator, may be one can take the conjugate (pre)Hilbert space $\overline{\mathfrak{k}}$ in the second slot, I mean $\mathfrak{h}=\mathfrak{k} \oplus \overline{\mathfrak{k}}$ ? Also this would make $f \mapsto \psi(f)$ anti-linear.

Comment: Hi Alan, yes, you're actually correct; with the Dirac fields defined as above, indeed we get $$\{\psi(f),\psi^*(g)\}=\frac{1}{2}(\{b(f),b^*(g)\}+\{c^*(f),c(g)\})=\frac{1}{2}(\{b(f),b^*(g)\}+\{c(g),c^*(f)\})=\frac{1}{2}(\langle f,g\rangle+\langle g,f\rangle)\mathbf{1}=\text{Re}\langle f,g\rangle\mathbf{1}\ .$$ I'll make appropriate amends to the answer. Thanks for the warning.

Comment: In due time: the different scalar multiplication for $\bar{\mathfrak{k}}$ affects the reconstruction of the fermionic creation and annihilation operators from the Dirac field operators. I'm a bit short on time to recall the precise details, so I'll omit that part for now to keep the answer clear for the time being and add the missing pieces later.